# Storing contents of a PHP array in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble storing array contents in mysql
I am using the code below

```
foreach($found_entry as $key => $sd) {
         echo "$key => $sd <br>";
$insert_found_row = mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable values ID = \"$sd[0]\" ,Folder = \"NULL\", Tsi = \"$sd[11]\", PT= \"NA\" ") or die(mysql_error());  
            echo "$sd";
```

If I echo the values I get

```
0 => ST10928
1 =>
2 => 2010-02-19 03:37:16
3 => \\fs1\
4 =>
5 =>
6 =>
7 =>
8 => M1
9 =>
10 =>
11 => LOG1.TXT
```

Comment: So what's wrong with it, actually?

Comment: If I use `$sd[0]`, only the first character is getting displayed.

Comment: What error do you get? Also your database-layout would be helpful. I guess you're having a problem with escaping your data, but without more information that's hard to say.

Answer (score 3):

Your query syntax is wrong. Use `SET` instead of `VALUES`. Also, you probably don't need the foreach loop at all, as you are referencing both `$sd[0]` and `$sd[11]`. Try something like this:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO
             myTable
         SET
             ID = '%s',
             folder = NULL,
             Tsi = '%s',
             PT = 'NA'",
             mysql_real_escape_string($found_entry[0]),
             mysql_real_escape_string($found_entry[11])
         );

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

`If I use $sd[0], only the first character is getting displayed.`

$sd is the value (e.g. "ST10928") of your array, but you're treating the value as an array itself, so $sd[0] must return only the first element (= letter).

If you're trying to insert values from your array into the database (instead of iterating through the array and slicing the values), maybe you should use `$found_entry[0]` instead of `$sd[0]` and `$found_entry[11]` for `$sd[11]` ??

Comment: yes, you are right. $sd is value of array, but I get different value in each loop, I am not able to figureout how to store these different values in different fields in mysql

Comment: I've edited my answer, try to use $found_entry instead of $sd and change your loop to execute the query for each "$found_entry".

Answer (score 0):

## Adding data to MySQL with a PHP Array

**Inserting data into MySQL**

In your code you are performing an insert for every field.

However, in most cases you know the field names before hand and so you can do a single INSERT with all of the fields.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_name (field_a,field_b,field_c) VALUES('.$found_entry['field_a'].','.$found_entry['field_b'].','.$found_entry['field_c'].');';
```

This cuts down on the number of queries required and so makes your code run faster and use less resources.

**Default values**

You can pass NULL when a value is not known and the DB should insert a default value.